# PFLogInViewController only show Facebook and Twitter login

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, twitter, parse-platform

I need a PFLogInViewController that shows *only* the Facebook and Twitter buttons for logging in. I have tried the code below but it never works. All of the references online tells me to do it exactly like this - and it still does not work. Please help.

```
-viewDidAppear {

PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];

    [logInViewController setDelegate:self];

    [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsTwitter];

[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

But this is all I get...

[image: two muppets]
<sub>(source: [parse.com](http://files.parse.com/7d9099c3-d480-46e5-b3d8-62b186bb2907/d4b8696c-90cc-4fe5-920c-ad9bcd24b80b-picture.png))</sub>

Why does "PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsTwitter" not work?

Comment: I vaguely remember having to add a PFLogInFieldsDismissButton to get it to work--quite a while back. Your code works fine for me with 1.2.19.

Comment: do you have in appdelegate  [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook] and  [PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey…. ?

Comment: and yes… @cloudsurfin has a good point, try: [logInViewController setFields: PFLogInFieldsTwitter | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];

Comment: THAT DID IT!! Thanks so much @ TonyMkenu. I was missing that.